# Use match to filter result in lookup? MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I quite can't get how should I use the pipeline to filter the resulting array of my look up here's the code

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d73d591b35c943a201837e2"),
    "itemName" : "Vape",
    "itemSellingPrice" : "350",
    "itemPurchasePrice" : "300",
    "itemAveragePurchasePrice" : "133.33333333333334",
    "itemBaseUnit" : "Unit 2",
    "itemReorderPoint" : "100",
    "itemTotalQuantity" : "300",
    "itemSumQuantity" : "500",
    "itemLocation" : "1",
    "itemSubLocation" : "sub loc 1",
    "itemDateCreated" : ISODate("2019-09-07T16:06:41.521Z"),
    "itemID" : 88,
    "__v" : 0,
    "salesData" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d73e23ed8422d2ba42049b4"),
            "salesOrderCustomerName" : "Manong Puring",
            "salesOrderInvoiceNumber" : "1123",
            "salesOrderAddress" : "Jan lang",
            "salesOrderPaymentStatus" : "Open",
            "salesOrderTotalPaid" : "0",
            "salesOrderTotalAmount" : "2800",
            "salesOrderDiscrepancyAmount" : "2800",
            "salesOrderItemList" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d73e23ed8422d2ba42049b5"),
                    "salesOrderSelectedItem" : "Vape",
                    "salesOrderAverage" : "133.33333333333334",
                    "salesOrderNewPrice" : "350",
                    "salesOrderPurchasePrice" : "300",
                    "salesOrderQuantity" : "8",
                    "salesOrderSubTotal" : "2800"
                }
            ],
            "salesOrderDateCreated" : ISODate("2019-09-07T16:00:00.000Z"),
            "salesOrderSubLocation" : "sub loc 1",
            "salesOrderLocation" : "1",
            "salesOrderID" : 62,
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d73e37164ade31b40775038"),
            "salesOrderCustomerName" : "Manong Puring",
            "salesOrderInvoiceNumber" : "123",
            "salesOrderAddress" : "Jan lang",
            "salesOrderPaymentStatus" : "Open",
            "salesOrderTotalPaid" : "0",
            "salesOrderTotalAmount" : "350",
            "salesOrderDiscrepancyAmount" : "350",
            "salesOrderItemList" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d73e37164ade31b40775039"),
                    "salesOrderSelectedItem" : "Vape",
                    "salesOrderAverage" : "133.33333333333334",
                    "salesOrderNewPrice" : "350",
                    "salesOrderPurchasePrice" : "300",
                    "salesOrderQuantity" : "1",
                    "salesOrderSubTotal" : "350"
                }
            ],
            "salesOrderDateCreated" : ISODate("2019-09-07T16:00:00.000Z"),
            "salesOrderSubLocation" : "sub loc 2",
            "salesOrderLocation" : "1",
            "salesOrderID" : 63,
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to get salesData with `salesOrderSubLocation: "sub loc 1"`
but it is showing data with sub loc 2 also. Searched for a while but can't find an exact problem with mine.

here's my query

```
db.getCollection('itemmodels').aggregate(

{ '$match': { itemName: 'Vape' } },
{ '$lookup':
     { 
       from: 'itemmodels',
       let: { "itemName": "$itemName" },
       pipeline: [
        { $match: {
          "salesOrderSubLocation": "sub loc 1",
          "salesOrderItemList.salesOrderSelectedItem": "$$itemName"
        }
        }
      ],
       as: 'salesData' 
    } 
})
```

any idea guys? I don't want to filter the result in the front end because it my cause some problems with tons of data in the future.

Comment: Are you looking up in the same collection? Also, your current query cannot produce the output you mentioned.

Comment: Yes that output was from the normal look up with localfield and foreignfield. No not same collections

Comment: Then please update the question accordingly.